# Cannot load Dojo modules with RequireJs

Tags: javascript, module, dojo, requirejs, amd

I think there is something I am missing. I have read that you can use dojo modules using RequireJS instead of using the Dojo loader. I'm semi comfortable with RequireJS and defining modules but I can't seem to figure out what is happening. I looked at the dojo js files and noticed that they were using define() just the same as when I declare my own modules. My files are organized like this

```
// File path
-js
    main.js
    - lib
        .require.js
        -dojo
            // All dojo files
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing but when I attempt to load a Dojo module the value is undefined.
Heres some sample HTML:

```
// index.html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        // include require script & set main.js
        <script data-main="js/main" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and a sample main.js file...

```
    // Sample main.js file

    // BaseUrl = js/

    require.config({
        packages : [
            name     : 'dojo',
            location : 'lib/dojo';
        ]
    });

    require(['dojo', 'dojo/dom'], function(dojo, dom) {

        // 'dojo'     should load dojo/main.js
        // 'dojo/dom' should load dojo/dom.js

        // But they have a value of "undefined" when I look at them in the console
        console.log(dojo);
    });
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? as a side note sometimes I get this error in the console

```
TypeError: _3.add is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

_3.add("dom-addeventlistener",!!document.addEventListener);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Quite an old post, but I'm wondering if you ever got requirejs and dojo loaded

Answer (score 1):

`_3.add("dom-addeventlistener",!!document.addEventListener);` is actually `has.add("dom-addeventlistener", !!document.addEventListener);`

The error `_3.add is not a function` is caused by the fact that requirejs unlike dojo's AMD implementation does not define the has.js API. Dojo tries to pull the has.js implementation from the AMD loader. If using a foreign loader, you must indicate it via dojoConfig. When running a minified build you need to add the `staticHasFeatures`  to the build profile:

```
staticHasFeatures: {
    "dojo-has-api": 0 // default 1
}
```

Doing so has solved the issue for me.

[Further info](https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/master/has.js)

Answer (score 1):

Put all your dojo files in js folder.

your folder structure should be like

```
// Folder structure
-js
    -dojo
    -dijit
    -dojox
```

Note: Make sure you provide the access to js/* path. So that url : http://localhost:8080/app/js/dojo/dojo.js accessible.

Then add dojo modules using requireJS using below script,

```
setTimeout(

    function() {
        var dojoConfig = {
            async : true
        };

    require.config({
        packages : 
            [ {
                name : 'dojo',
                location : '../js/dojo'
            } ],    
    });

    require(
        [ 'dojo', 'dojo/dom' ],
        function(dojo, dom) {
            console.log(dojo);
            dom.byId("myDiv").innerHTML = "updatedHTML content";
    });

}, 1000);
```

thats it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your package config definition is an array of object:

```
require.config({
    packages : [
        {
            name     : 'dojo',
            location : 'lib/dojo';
        }
    ]
});
```

After, well, you should check in your devtools network tab to make sure require.js is loading the right file and that the path is good. Remember that `location` is relative to the `baseUrl`.

Hope this help !

Comment: Isnt the packages config supposed to be an array of object w/ params for the package? And I'm aware that the location is relative to the baseUrl. In my example 'dojo' should load js/lib/dojo/main.js. But the dojo object has a value of "undefined"...

Comment: Well, if you don't need special setting, you can just define the `name` in the config, but else you need an object :

require.config({
    packages: [
        "cart",
        {
            name: "store",
            main: "store"
        }
    ]
});

Answer (score 0):

`_3` is an indicator that you are using the minified, standalone distribution of dojo. If you want to use Dojo with a different loader, I believe you want to be using the Source/SDK download from [their download page](http://dojotoolkit.org/download/).